# How to make a JS function wait for the component to be loaded in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular11

I want to get the width of a component in angular after being loaded, but it returns 0 because the because the div isn't loaded yet, even if I write the code inside AfterViewInit. The only solution that makes it work in development is to set a timeout to a 100ms. Is there a cleaner and better way to do it?

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}
```

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(function (){
      console.log(document.getElementById('test').clientWidth);
    }, 100)
  }
```

Comment: I had to use this technique once. I needed to wait for DOM loaded to pass ID of "select" tag element inside Angular template to external JS-file to style it. Did you find more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your `setTimeout` in `ngAfterViewChecked()` life cycle hook rather than `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Also, you can use `viewChild()` directive as well to solve your problem with more clearer way. It won't need the `setTimeout` as well.

```
The ViewChild decorated variable elementView is only set after the ngAfterViewInit life cycle hook:

import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './src/app.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('content') elementView: ElementRef;

  contentWidth: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.contentWidth= this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
  }
}
```